# Debug assertion failed _crtisValidHeapPointer(block)

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I'm trying to implement quick sort in c/c++ and I keep getting this error, "Debug assertion failed _crtisValidHeapPointer(block)" anytime I run the code.

My code is:

```
void QuickSort(int *A, int size) {
if (size < 2) return;
int *L = NULL, *R = NULL, RSize = 0, LSize = 0;

R = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
L = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (A[size - 1] <= A[i]) 
        if( ((int *)realloc(R, (sizeof(int) * (RSize + 2) ))) != NULL )
            R[RSize++] = A[i];
    else 
        if ( ((int *)realloc(L, (sizeof(int) * (LSize + 2) ))) != NULL )
            L[LSize++] = A[i];
}

    QuickSort(L, LSize);
    QuickSort(R, RSize);
    Merge(A, L, R, LSize, RSize);
    free(L);
    free(R);
    return;
}
```

I know it has to do with the memory allocation of my arrays L and R, but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is exactly.

EDIT: Solution found

Code:

```
void QuickSort(int *A, int size) {
if (size < 2) return;
int *L = NULL, *R = NULL, RSize = 0, LSize = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (A[size - 2] < A[i]) {
        if ((R = (int *)realloc(R, (sizeof(int) * (RSize + 1)))) != NULL) 
            R[RSize++] = A[i];
    }
    else {
        if ((L = (int *)realloc(L, (sizeof(int) * (LSize + 1)))) != NULL) 
            L[LSize++] = A[i];
    }
}
     QuickSort(L, LSize);
     QuickSort(R, RSize);
     Merge(A, L, R, LSize, RSize);
     free(L);
     free(R);
     return;
}
```

Comment: Is this c++ or c, they are not the same.

Comment: Also please provide a minimal runable example and the line where your problem occurred. Finally, have you stepped through this code with a debugger and checked all your pointer dereferences to ensure you are not going out of bounds on any of these arrays?

Comment: Its in C, but for simplicity I've declared 'i' in the for loop which is a C++ practice.

Comment: I'm using visual studio c++, and the debugger is not telling me where the problem is, and there is no minimal runnable example. The code isn't working because of this bug.

Comment: @Hossam No, because you never assign the return value of `realloc()` (you just compare them to `NULL`).  Actually, after your `realloc` call, the arrays no longer point to valid memory, which corrupts the heap.

Comment: @RyanBemrose, thanks! Your advice worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if( ((int *)realloc(R, (sizeof(int) * (RSize + 2) ))) != NULL )
    R[RSize++] = A[i];
```

The `realloc` function *returns* the new array pointer, which is compared to NULL inside the `if`, and then discarded.  Then the original (invalid) pointer is dereferenced, corrupting the heap.

To fix, be sure to assign the result of `realloc` to the pointer.

```
if( (R = (int *)realloc(R, (sizeof(int) * (RSize + 2) ))) != NULL )
```

You should also include some error checking to abort the loop, in case the allocation fails, in the form of an `else` statement to this `if`.  As currently written, if `realloc` fails then the loop will continue to completion, skipping the array on each iteration, and then return a corrupted result.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is allocation only for single `int` to both variables `L` and `R`. But later in the code you assign many integers as the `LSize` and `RSize` is incremented. Well, I see `realloc` is called but the result is not assigned back to `L` and `R` so this causes issues.

Anyway the quicksort algorithm may very well work on the original array, there is no reason to allocate new temporary arrays for it.

Comment: I allocate for only one int for L and R, but later I do realloc() more space as LSize and RSize increment.

Comment: @Hossam : Sorry, I just noticed. But there is an error - the result of `realloc` is not assigned back to `L` and `R`.